# Probability of guessing right all questions but one given short time

Tags: probability

I was asked by a (pissed off) friend which is the probability of guessing right 174 out of 175 true/false questions in 45 minutes, since he suspect that the person who achieved this was somehow cheating.

Aside the context itself, I thought it is a nice probability exercise.

What informations do I need to compute such probability? This is certainly not a random guess problem.
I guess I need a prior probability distribution for the number of right guesses and number of questions answered per minute (or number of guesses in 45 minutes) of the whole class, right?
Then I have to compute the probability of having a cases such extreme or more in a multivariate (right guesses X answers per minute). Which distributions would be appropriate?

Also, it's ok to use sufficient statistics for such priors or given the small number of students (n = 25)?

I am still learning in probability so I would appreciate a formal explanation (Bayesian, frequentist, or both)